# Addition of type timedelta and int giving "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_rates and df_profit as shown below. df_rates has a time-date value its column name with values as certain rates and the index values denotes the minutes before the time-date value of the column. (i.e. row 1 denotes 0 mins before 2012-03-31 23:45:00, row 2 denotes 5 mins before 2012-03-31 23:45:00 and so on). Whereas df_profit has timestamps as its index and there is a Profit column.

To achieve a new data frame based on certain conditions, I implemented the below code, but I am getting the following error "**TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str**" . I do not understand the occurrence of this error since there is no string. Can someone please help with this?

```
df_rates
Mins before time     2012-03-31 23:45:00
0                        113.1
5                        112.1
10                       113.1
15                       113.17
20                       103.17
25                       133.17
30                       101.39

df_profit
                         Profit
2012-04-01 00:30:00      251.71
2012-04-01 00:15:00      652.782
2012-04-01 00:00:00      458.099
2012-03-31 23:45:00      3504.664
2012-03-31 23:30:00      1215.76
2012-03-31 23:15:00     -21.48
2012-03-31 23:00:00     -8.538
2012-03-31 22:40:00     -5.11
```

Code : 'anchor_time' is of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> , lookback_minutes is of type <class 'int'>,

```
anchor_time = df_rates.columns[-1]
lookback_minutes = 30
df_rates = ( df_rates
    .set_index(anchor_time - pd.to_timedelta(df_rates['Mins before time'] + lookback_minutes, unit='min'))
    .join(df_profit).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: You probably have a specialized `Time` class and a simple `integer` class conflicting. You should try looking for a way to convert `lookback_minutes` into a timestamp object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I think you wanted to do something like this, I don't know if this is your expected end result but it will allow you to keep going.

Note that the error was trying to manipulate strings as time objects.

```
import datetime 
import pandas as pd

lookback_minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
anchor_time = df_rates.columns[-1]

df_profit.index = pd.to_datetime(df_profit.index)
df_rates = df_rates.set_index(pd.to_datetime(anchor_time) - (pd.to_timedelta(df_rates["Mins before time"],"minutes")) + lookback_minutes)
df_merged = df_rates.join(df_profit)
df_merged.index.names = ['Datetime']
df_merged
```

Output:

| Datetime | Mins before time | 2012-03-31 23:45:00 | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-04-01 00:15:00 | 0 | 113.10 | 652.782 |
| 2012-04-01 00:10:00 | 5 | 112.10 | NaN |
| 2012-04-01 00:05:00 | 10 | 113.10 | NaN |
| 2012-04-01 00:00:00 | 15 | 113.17 | 458.099 |
| 2012-03-31 23:55:00 | 20 | 103.17 | NaN |
| 2012-03-31 23:50:00 | 25 | 133.17 | NaN |
| 2012-03-31 23:45:00 | 30 | 101.39 | 3504.664 |